# How to assign a return value of a throwable function inside a try catch?

Tags: ios, swift4

I'm new to Swift, I'm following the documentation of this method inside `networkExtension`:

```
open class NEVPNConnection : NSObject {
    /*!
         * @method startVPNTunnelAndReturnError:
         * @discussion This function is used to start the VPN tunnel using the current VPN configuration. The VPN tunnel connection process is started and this function returns immediately.
         * @param error If the VPN tunnel was started successfully, this parameter is set to nil. Otherwise this parameter is set to the error that occurred. Possible errors include:
         *    1. NEVPNErrorConfigurationInvalid
         *    2. NEVPNErrorConfigurationDisabled
         * @return YES if the VPN tunnel was started successfully, NO if an error occurred.
         */
        @available(iOS 8.0, *)
        open func startVPNTunnel() throws
```

The way I understand it, if it returns true, the VPN connection has been established.

This is my code:

```
                    let result: Bool?
                    do {
                        result = try self.vpnManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
                        if result! {
                            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .enableDisconnect, object: nil)
                        }
                    } catch let error {
                        print("Error starting VPN Connection \(error.localizedDescription)");
                    }
```

However at this line:

```
result = try self.vpnManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
```

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'Bool?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation refers to the Objective-C method.

An Objective-C method `-(BOOL)doSomethingAndReturnError:(NSError *...` is exposed to Swift as `doSomething() throws`.

So the Swift method doesn't have a return value. You can simply write

```
   do {
       try self.vpnManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
       NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .enableDisconnect, object: nil)
   } catch {
      print("Error starting VPN Connection \(error.localizedDescription)");
   }
```

---

But even if the method was returning a `Bool` never use an optional in this case, use something like this:

```
let result: Bool
do {
   result = try doSomething()    
} catch {
   result = false
   print("Error starting VPN Connection \(error.localizedDescription)");
}
if result {
   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .enableDisconnect, object: nil)
}
```

Comment: Documentation is not wrong, but it documents ObjC method, which indeed returns `BOOL` value. It's Swift preparser/obj-c-declaration-converter(? does it have proper name?) turns all `-(BOOL)doSomethingAndReturnError:(NSError * _Nullable *)error` into `func doSomething() throws`.

Comment: @user28434 Thanks for the hint. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The function `startVPNTunnel` returns `Void`. not `Bool`. Try this:

```
    do {
        try self.vpnManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()

        // If function reached that point startVPNTunnel didn't throw error
    } catch let error {
        // Some error
    }
```